# Put a table of values as an argument to a query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to do something like this:

```
SET @MyTableAsArgument = 'Foo;Bar\n1;2\n3;4\n'; -- CSV or any other table-format
SET @AnOtherArgument = 'somedata';

SELECT * FROM table1 t1, @MyTableAsArgument t2
WHERE t1.foo = t2.foo
AND t1.bar = @AnOtherArgument
```

Is there a way to do this?

The only other solution I see is:

1. Create a temporary table `tmp1`
2. Insert my `MyTableAsArgument` to the `tmp1`
3. Do My query on `table1` and `tmp1`
4. Delete my temporary table `tmp1`

I am not sure if this is an abuse of temporary tables.
Is there a significant performance overhead with temporary tables as they are used for queries?

Comment: Could your give us some sameple data for your question?

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a table variable or temporary table?

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (foo VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO @MyTable (foo)
    VALUES ('Foo'), ('Bar\n12\n3'), ('4\n');

SET @AnOtherArgument = 'somedata';

SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.foo IN (SELECT foo FROM @MyTable) AND
      t1.bar = @AnOtherArgument;
```

If this is not possible, you can use a `SPLIT()` functions -- `STRING_SPLIT()` is built into the most recent versions -- but other versions are on the web:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.foo IN (SELECT foo FROM string_split(@MyTableLIST, ';') ss(foo)) AND
      t1.bar = @AnOtherArgument;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Cosinus, there is a temp table variable too in SQL. This allows you to define the columns you want in that table and using a 'union all' you can insert elements in that table.
See this mockup below.

```
DECLARE @MyTableAsArgument table(Name varchar(20), foo varchar(50), descb varchar(100), pj_id int)

DECLARE @AnOtherArgument varchar(20) = 'somedata';

INSERT into @MyTableAsArgument
SELECT 'James', 'iphone', 'cell phone', 1 union all
SELECT 'Michael', 'macbook', 'laptop', 2 union all
SELECT 'Henry', 'windows', 'os', 3 



SELECT * 
FROM 
    table1 t1

    Join @MyTableAsArgument t2 ON
        t1.foo = t2.foo
        AND 
        t1.bar = @AnOtherArgument
```